# Make names of files and folders display fully in the Mac OS X Finder

Tags: macos, mac, finder

I am not normally a Mac person, however, my father has a Mac and finds it frustrating to need to click on items with long names in order to display the full name. Is there any way to get around this? (for example by making the text smaller)

Comment: not quite what i had in mind, my father is not that computer savy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It IS possible to make the text size smaller.

Click on the desktop. Hit Command "J" brings up folder options. Pick a smaller text size.

You can also do this to ALL folders. Open any folder and hit Command "J" again. If you have a newer version of OSX you can change the text size and "Use as default."

Not to proselytize, but it's always a good idea to make filenames as short and logical as possible. As long as you can tell a file's contents are, that's good enough. Cross-platform issues might truncate these names into an unrecognizable mess. Experience is a harsh mistress.

Comment: If we reflect on the percentage of filenames on our computers we wrote ourselves, we might see how it's unreasonable to think we can alleviate this problem by renaming all the files on our computers.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use List View or Column View and drag the column separators to set the columns wide.

Comment: this works in finder, is there any alternative for the desktop though?

Comment: @ForUs You can view the Desktop's contents in a Finder window just like any other folder. It's `~/Desktop/`. Otherwise I'm not aware of a way. FWIW, note that you don't have to click, you can just hover.

Comment: This is not a solution, because you would have to do this click-and-drag everytime. We cant the column to expand automatically.

Answer (score 1):

After years of struggling with this, it's my belief that Apple's intended workaround for **keyboard users** with this problem is:

**Switch to "List View" (⌘2) when you need to see longer filenames.**

*This habit requires an understanding of what folder will present itself. Otherwise, it's disorienting. Note the **title bar** or the **item highlighted in blue**.*

Each view has its own strength:
"Icon" (⌘1) - files overview
"List" (⌘2) – file details
"Column" (⌘3) – navigating folders
"Cover Flow" (⌘4) - media browsing

For mouse-lovers in "Column" view, you can double-click the handle at the bottom of the column:

[image: column handle]

Answer (score 0):

You can double click the line that separates the "Name" heading from whatever is next to it (I'm talking about the little line you would press to drag and expand the file names). Just double click it and it will show the full name until you press the "name" heading again.

Comment: He already acknowledges this in his question - do you know of a way to make showing the full name the default?